# Rails - Query time shifts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, time

currently I'm developing a system that manages work shifts.

The system contains an endpoint that returns the current shift based on server time. I created a query that works fine for regular shifts like 08:00 AM to 04:00 PM and so on but the challenge is when there is a dawn shift that starts at 10:00 PM until 06:00 AM from the other day.

My model contains the following fields:

- name (String)
- start_at (Time)
- end_at (Time)

*Ps.: I'm using Postgres as the database.*

My code:

```
class Shift < ApplicationRecord
  def self.current
    current_time = Time.now()
    current_time = current_time.change(year: 2000, month: 1, day: 1)

    @current ||= Shift
                  .where('start_time <= ?', current_time)
                  .where('end_time >= ?', current_time)
                  .first()
  end
end
```

*Ps.: I guess, since I'm using the Time type in the database, I have to normalize the **Time.now** to use the 2000 - 01 - 01 date.*

So, is there an easy/best way to do that?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Don't know if it is viable for you, but why not convert datatype of `start_at` and `end_at` to `datetime`? You could simply check if DateTime.now is in between.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting problem! So there's two cases: (1) a normal shift (where `start_time <= end_time`), and (2) a shift that overlaps midnight (where `start_time > end_time`).

You are already handling the first case by checking if the current time is between the start time and the end time.

I believe the second case can be handled by checking if the current time is *either* between the start time and midnight, *or* between midnight and the end time. Which translates to `start_time <= ? OR end_time >= ?`.

I haven't used Rails in a while, but I think you could do something like this:

```
@current ||= Shift
  .where('start_time <= end_time')
  .where('start_time <= ?', current_time)
  .where('end_time >= ?', current_time)
  .or(Shift
    .where('start_time > end_time')
    .or(Shift
      .where('start_time <= ?', current_time)
      .where('end_time >= ?', current_time)))
  .first()
```

If you go with this, consider splitting the two cases into separate [scopes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes), so you can write something more readable like this in this method:

```
@current ||= current_normal_shifts.or(current_dawn_shifts).first
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in the [tod gem](https://github.com/jackc/tod) that provides a `TimeOfDay` class and a `Shift` class that takes two `TimeOfDay` objects to represent the start and end of the shift. It handles dawn shifts as expected.

An implementation might look like this:

```
require 'tod'

class Shift < ApplicationRecord
  def self.current
    find(&:current?)
  end

  def current?
    schedule.include?(Tod::TimeOfDay(Time.now))
  end

  def schedule
    Tod::Shift.new(Tod::TimeOfDay(start_time), Tod::TimeOfDay(end_time))
  end
end
```